# No Resource Identifier Found for Attribute textIsSelectable repeateadly occurs

Tags: android, eclipse

I use Eclipse 4.3.0 with the latest Android SDK.
I have a textview which looks like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="onSave"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

I added the line **android:textIsSelectable="false"** manually because lint gave me a warning and I hate to have warnings. The warning goes away. However, as soon as I edit something in the layout, an error appears saying:

**error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'textIsSelectable' in package 'android'**

I have to go to the file, remove the line, the error disappears and the warning returns. Then I reinsert the line again, and the error AND the warning is gone, until next time I have to edit something.

This property is also not showing up anywhere in the editor screen, so maybe that is the reason, but then, how can I get rid permanently of this error loop? Or is this a bug in the SDK environment?

Comment: TextIsSelectable was added in API 11.  What are your min and target API levels?  And what OS is your emulator/phone?

Comment: I installed three target environments 2.2, 2.3.3 and 4.2.2. So you mean, when I select 4.2.2 this goes ayway? I assume that for the other environments, this should be ignored though? Just checked, and it doesn't change.

Comment: I would expect it to work on 4.2.2 and not on the others.  You can make it work either by having a separate layout for v11, or by setting that attribute programatically and only if the version is 11 or higher.

Comment: Setting it programmatically doesn't make it go away in the warning view. The text view is just a label, so I don't care if the user can select and copy it. Wouldn't make sense in this case anyway. So should I use a different control? Is there a label item in android, like JLabel, which doesn't cause this warning?

Comment: No, textviews are your labels.  If you're using eclipse, sometimes these things clear up if you do a clean and compile with another file as the currently edited file in eclipse.  If so its lint being overly picky and you need to tell it to ignore that, or change your target sdk to >11 (target isn't minimum, it won't stop it from running on 2.2 or 2.3).